# How to make callback from one Class to Adapter in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, interface, callback

When the center is activated, then there should be a call back to the Adapter class, which updates the list and make changes.
Code for the Activation of the centre:

```
public class ActivatePresenter extends BasePresenter<ActivateMvpView> {
//instance of the interface.
private Callback callback;

//method which makes the centre active

public void activateCenter(final int centerId, ActivatePayload activatePayload) {
    checkViewAttached();
    getMvpView().showProgressbar(true);
    subscriptions.add(dataManagerCenter.activateCenter(centerId, activatePayload)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<GenericResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    getMvpView().showProgressbar(false);
                    getMvpView().showError(MFErrorParser.errorMessage(e));
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(GenericResponse genericResponse) {


       
                    getMvpView().showProgressbar(false);

                    getMvpView().showActivatedSuccessfully(
                            R.string.center_activated_successfully);


                //here the center gets activated, and thus the method is called

                    if(callback != null) {
                        callback.onSuccess();
                    }


                }
            })
    );
}
```

Interface which I have made for the call back:

```
    public interface Callback{
    public void onSuccess();
}
```

Code for Adapter:(only those methods mentioned which are used here.)

```
 public class CentersListAdapter extends SelectableAdapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements 
 ActivatePresenter.Callback {

 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {  if (center.getActive()) {

           // if center is active, then it will set the color to green
            ((ViewHolder) holder).ivStatusIndicator.setImageDrawable(
                    Utils.setCircularBackground(R.color.light_green, context));

        } else {
           // if the center is not active, then it will set the color to red
            ((ViewHolder) holder).ivStatusIndicator.setImageDrawable(
                    Utils.setCircularBackground(R.color.light_red, context));
        }

@Override
public void onSuccess() {
    ivStatusIndicator.setImageDrawable(
            
            // should set the color of shape to green when the center gets activated

            Utils.setCircularBackground(R.color.light_green, context));
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}}}
```

When the client is activated, there should be a callback to adapter to update the list.

**But now the adapter is not updating even when the center is activated.
Please help me to find the problem in the above code, i.e., why it is not updating the list.**

Comment: Do you ever assign a value to `callback`? The code which you posted doesn't contain that, which is why `if(callback != null)` will always be false.

Comment: I understood, but I am not able to write the code for that, I'd be grateful if you could please share the code for the same, just that part of code in which we assign value to callback.

Comment: Do you have the code where you create a `CentersListAdapter` and assign it to a recyclerView?